# How to Configure Single SSL for wildcard entry

Tags: web-services, security, web, ssl-certificate

We have a web application "example.com" with SSL integrated.The SSL is registered for "example.com". Now we want to access the application using xyz.example.com(or any sub domains). The access from sub domains to "example.com" is made using the wildcard entry in DNS (ie "*.example.com"). Im getting SSL error when I try to access the site using "xyx.example.com". What should I do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your certificate is probably issued for particular domain name. You need to purchase (or create a self-signed) wild-card certificate, where one of Subject Alternative Name extensions is `*.example.com`.

A side note: SSL can not be "registered" - that's a protocol. You have an X.509 certificate issued for the particular domain name.